# Check if a file exists inside a "Variable" Path

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command

I am trying to find if a file exist in an iPhone application directory

Unfortunately, apps directory differs from a device to another

On my device, i use the following command to see if the file exists:

```
if  [[ -f "/var/mobile/Applications/D0D2B991-3CDA-457B-9187-1F02A84FF3AB/AppName.app/filename.txt" ]]; then 
    echo "The File Exists"; 
else
    echo "The File Does Not Exist";
fi
```

I want a command that would automatically search if the file exist without the need to specify the "variable" name inside the path.

I tried this:

```
if  [[ -f "/var/mobile/Applications/*/AppName.app/filename.txt" ]]; then 
    echo "The File Exists"; 
else 
    echo "The File Does Not Exist"; 
fi
```

But no luck, it didn't find the file,

Maybe because i have 2 path of `/var/mobile/Applications/*/AppName.app/` since i have cloned the app.

I would like to get a way to be able to find if the file `filename.txt` exists inside any folder named `AppName.app` inside this directory `/var/mobile/Applications/*/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
[[ $(find /var/mobile/Applications/*/AppName.app/ -name filename.txt -print -quit | wc -l) -gt 0 ]] && echo "The File Exists" || echo "The File Does Not Exist"
```

Comment: Thanks, i added Applications/*/AppName.app/ to the directory which made the search faster! `[[ $(find /var/mobile/Applications/*/AppName.app/ -name filename.txt | wc -l) -gt 0 ]] && echo "The File Exists" || echo "The File Does Not Exist"`

Comment: @F0u4d Assuming you're not doing anything in the results, you should do `-print -quit` so `find` stops searching after finding one.

Answer (score 2):

The `-f` test can only take one argument. You would need to put it in a loop to check if some glob exists and its matches some regular file, i.e.

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob
found=
for file in /var/mobile/Applications/*/AppName.app/filename.txt; do
  [[ -f $file ]] && found=: && break
done
[[ -n $found ]] && echo "The File Exists" || echo "The File Does Not Exist"
```

If you're not sure specifically where the file is located you can use [find](/questions/tagged/find), doing something like below which will exit early if found. (should work for `gnu` [find](/questions/tagged/find), haven't tested on `bsd`)

```bsh
if [[ -f $(find /some_root_directory -type f -name 'filename.txt' -print -quit) ]]; then
    echo "The File Exists"
else
    echo "The File Does Not Exist"
fi
```

Comment: Works fine in BSD as well ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
# if a glob matches nothing, remove it instead of leaving the literal glob
shopt -s nullglob 

# stick all matches in an array
files=( /var/mobile/Applications/*/AppName.app/filename.txt )

case "${#files[@]}" in
  0 ) echo "Sorry, no such file." ;;
  1 ) echo "The file exists: ${files[0]}" ;;
  * ) echo "There are multiple files matching this pattern: ${files[*]}" ;;
esac
```

Comment: Think OP meant regular file given his use of the `-f` test.

Comment: Thank you, your method worked aswell but with little change to the other answer i found it better for my case.

Answer (score 0):

I like this technique for the purpose:

```
if find /var/mobile/Applications/*/AppName.app/ -name filename.txt -print -quit | grep -q .; then
    echo "The File Exists"
else
    echo "The File Does Not Exist"
fi
```

This has some advantages over this form:

```
[[ $(find ..... -print -quit | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]
```

Because:

- It doesn't need a `$()` subshell
- It doesn't need to count lines with `wc`
- It doesn't need to compare numbers with the `-gt` operator
- It doesn't need to be inside a `[[ ... ]]`

Basically it's a `find ... | grep -q .` versus `[[ $(find ... | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]`

Or `find ... | grep -q .` versus `[[ -f $(find ...) ]]`